# How to have vanishing cell bracket for all notebook

Tags: notebooks

I know that it is possible to make the cell brackets appear only when the mouse is upon them but I do not know how to do that. Of course for one cell it is shown in the documentation but not for an entire notebook.

Comment: [ref / ShowCellBracket](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowCellBracket.html) / Details: `ShowCellBracket->Automatic `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary setting:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, "ShowCellBracket" -> False]
```

Fixed setting:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, "ShowCellBracket" -> False]
```

Only for a given notebook:

```
SetOptions[nb, "ShowCellBracket" -> False]
```

Comment: This hides them completely.  Should it not be `Automatic` instead as Kuba comments?

Comment: With Automatic as sugested by mr Wizard s c de V commands are perfect.